# Meaning of *(volatile unsigned int *) 0x00 = 0x00;

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of the following line of code?

```
*(volatile unsigned int *) 0x00 = 0x00;
```

It is used in Assert definition:

```
void Assert()
{
    // (some other code above)

    *(volatile unsigned int *) 0x00 = 0x00;

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can guess it is trying to cause the program to crash with a segmentation fault or something similar.

Whoever wrote the code was thinking "I hope the compiler does not optimize this crash away, so let's put a volatile in front of the pointer dereference".

But all the code is doing is causing undefined behavior that is not guaranteed to crash.

An `std::terminate()` is a much better option if you want your program to terminate then that UB `Assert()`

Also note that an assert should be given a condition, and then if the condition is false the assert should trigger some failure code.  Ot is not meant to be an "exit this program" function. See [linked comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669294/meaning-of-volatile-unsigned-int-0x00-0x00/44669407?noredirect=1#comment76326138_44669407)

Comment: Then again, an `assert` is not an attempt to terminate a program. It issues a diagnostic message, and in this case (as is common, too), it tries to get the debugger's attention. This leaves the entire call stack intact for inspection, at the point of error. Much more helpful than terminating the program. Note: While being undefined behavior, the statement exhibits fairly predictable behavior across a wide range of platforms.

Comment: @IInspectable noted in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Cast 0x00 to pointer to `volatile unsigned int` and then dereference it with operator`*` and write to that address 0x00. Which is undefined behavior and on most systems will cause crash.